# Getting repository commit messages with Ant to update Crashlytics Beta release notes for builds using VSTS or Bitrise

Tags: android, git, azure-devops, crashlytics-beta, bitrise

I´m kind of new with the CI thing so I would appreciate a as much details as you folks can provide me.

I have configured two build servers for different native Android applications, one is using Bitrise and the other VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services), I have also configured a Fabric account with the Crashlytics/Beta kit enabled to automatically distribute the APK in each build.
I need to add a build step or some configuration, maybe using Ant or whatever, to update the release notes for each build uploaded to Fabric for testing purposes using the messages from the commits in the repository.

Thanks in advance!

---

Here are the screenshots of my VSTS configuration

Powershell Script:
[image]

Ant script:
[image]

And the screenshot of both build.xml (Ant) and script_release_notes.txt (Powershell), which are in the root folder:
[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If during the build flow, you can save the commits to a .txt file, you could then upload that through the Ant Beta release command: -DbetaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath=release_notes.txt

Comment: Thanks Mike. Actually that is one part, which I´m doing manually. What I need is to automatically get the data from the commits so I can somehow create de file and upload it.

Comment: Ahh, okay! Sorry, but I'm less familiar with that side of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of Bitrise, if you use the `Git Clone` step that exposes the commit information as environment variables, which you can then use anywhere you want to, like any other environment variable.

You can find the full list of exported "outputs" (environment variables) of the Git Clone step here: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-git-clone/blob/master/step.yml#L80

Edit: If you want to save these into a `release_notes.txt` file you can simply `echo "$the_env_var" >> release_notes.txt`, e.g. with a `Script` step.

To save the full commit message into release notes:

```
#!/bin/bash
# fail if any commands fails
set -e
# debug log
set -x

echo "$GIT_CLONE_COMMIT_MESSAGE_SUBJECT" > release_notes.txt
echo "$GIT_CLONE_COMMIT_MESSAGE_BODY" >> release_notes.txt
```

Comment: Hi Viktor thanks a lot, actually the answer partially worked. Now I´m having only the information for the last commit as part of the release notes. How can I get the information from previous commits, ideally all commits since last build?

Comment: @AlejandroCasanovaMutis there's no env var for that right now - you can find the related feature request with description about why this is not a trivial thing here: https://bitrise.uservoice.com/forums/235233-general/suggestions/6901955-expose-previous-build-information-e-g-git-commit

Answer (score 0):

For VSTS build, you can add a PowerShell script task to get the commit messages of current build via [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#changes).

Following is a sample powershell script to get this, you need to enable "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" option in your build definition to use this script.

```
$collectionuri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$buildid = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$basicAuth= ("{0}:{1}"-f "anys",$token)
$basicAuth=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

$url= $collectionuri + $project + "/_apis/build/builds/" + $buildID + "/changes?api-version=2.0"

$getbuildchanges = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Get | select value

foreach ($commit in $getbuildchanges.value)
{
    Write-Host $commit.id;
    $commit.id | Out-File -filepath commitmessages.txt -Append;
    Write-Host $commit.message;
    $commit.message | Out-File -filepath commitmessages.txt -Append;
}
```

Update: Please try with following script:

```
$collectionuri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$buildid = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$basicAuth= ("{0}:{1}"-f "anys",$token)
$basicAuth=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

$url= $collectionuri + $project + "/_apis/build/builds/" + $buildID + "/changes?api-version=2.0"

$getbuildchanges = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Get;

if($getbuildchanges.count -ne 0)
{
foreach ($commit in $getbuildchanges.value)
{
    Write-Host $commit.id;
    $commit.id | Out-File -filepath release_notes.txt -Append;
    Write-Host $commit.message;
    $commit.message | Out-File -filepath release_notes.txt -Append;
}
}
else
{
    $nocommitfound = "There is no commit related to current build.";
    Write-Host $nocommitfound;
    $nocommitfound | Out-File -filepath release_notes.txt -Append;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eddie - MSFT. Now the build is failing with this error 
FileNotFoundException: release_notes.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
This is the output for the powerShell script:
2016-10-12T15:59:48.0606069Z ##[section]Starting: Generate commit summary for release notes
##[command]. 'C:\a\1\s\script_release_notes.txt' 
##[section]Finishing: Generate commit summary for release notes
The parameter I´m using for the file is -DfilePath=release_notes.txt. I updated the script with this file name.
Any ideas?

Comment: @AlejandroCasanovaMutis Can you share your updated script? I cannot reproduce the issue at my side with the file name changed to "release_notes.txt".

Comment: The script is exactly the same you asnwered, the changes are just this two lines:
....
$commit.id | Out-File -filepath release_notes.txt -Append;
   ...
$commit.message | Out-File -filepath release_notes.txt -Append;

Is there a way to output the file name/path just to be sure it is generating it?

Comment: @AlejandroCasanovaMutis Please try with the updated code in my answer to see if it works.

Comment: I have the same result with the updated script. Cannot find release_notes.txt. The log from powershell keeps saying -- ##[command]. 'C:\a\1\s\script_release_notes.txt' I don´t see any evidence of the file I need (release_notes.txt) or its location. How can I know that?

Comment: @AlejandroCasanovaMutis Can you share the settings of your build definition? It's trying to find the "script_release_notes.txt" file while the script generate "release_notes.txt".

Comment: Please check the updates in the question with the settings of both new steps (powershell and Ant).